# not able to logout of airflow 2.1.1 after integrating with keycloak(OAUTH2)

Tags: airflow, flask-security, flask-appbuilder

I have installed airflow2.1.1 on centos7 VM.
I have integrated with keycloak using OAUTH provider configuration.
I am able to login but not able to logout.

Its throwing "**access is denied**" error on UI.

[image]

Please find below OAUTH config properties

```
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OAUTH
import os
import json
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "User"


# a mapping from the values of `userinfo["role_keys"]` to a list of FAB roles
AUTH_ROLES_MAPPING = {
    "FAB_USERS": ["User"],
    "FAB_ADMINS": ["Admin"],
}


OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
    {'name':'google', 'icon':'fa-google', 'token_key':'access_token',
        'remote_app': {
            'client_id':'airflow',
            'client_secret':'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'api_base_url':'https://keycloak-1.dastc.stee.com:8443/auth/realms/sep',
            'client_kwargs':{
              'scope': 'email profile openid roles'
            },
            'request_token_url':None,
            'access_token_url':'https://keycloak-1.dastc.stee.com:8443/auth/realms/sep/protocol/openid-connect/token',
            'authorize_url':'https://keycloak-1.dastc.stee.com:8443/auth/realms/sep/protocol/openid-connect/auth',
            'userinfo_endpoint':'https://keycloak-1.dastc.stee.com:8443/auth/realms/sep/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo',
            'logout_redirect_url':'https://keycloak-1.dastc.stee.com:8443/auth/realms/sep/protocol/openid-connect/logout'}
    }
]
```

Can anyone please help me debug this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: The same issue (UI error) is reported and I think it is "In-Progress" https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/15601

Comment: is this issue still resolved?